# When Closing a Jquery Dialog, the shading from the modal will not go away

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

When I open the jquery dialog everything works just fine, until I try to close it, either by selecting a user or pressing escape.  Then the jquery dialog box goes away, but the shading/mask from the modal option will not go away.  I forced my app to use Jquery 1.8.3 and it worked just fine.  I can not find what change would do this.  Any help is awesome thanks!

```
$("#user_id_mask").focus(function()
        {
            $("#user_selection_dialog").dialog(
            {
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                modal: true
            });
        });

        $("#first_name").keyup(function()
        {
            if($.trim($(this).val()).length >= 2)
                $.get("/admin/users/get_options?first_name=" + $.trim($(this).val()) + "&last_name=" + $.trim($("#last_name").val()), updateUserResults);
        });

        $("#last_name").keyup(function()
        {
            if($.trim($(this).val()).length >= 2)
                $.get("/admin/users/get_options?last_name=" + $.trim($(this).val()) + "&first_name=" + $.trim($("#first_name").val()), updateUserResults);
        });

        $("#user_search_results").on("click", "tr", function(event)
        {
            $("#<%= f.object.class.to_s.underscore %>_user_id").val($(this).data("userId"));
            $("#user_id_mask").val($(this).data("label"));
            $("#user_selection_dialog").dialog("close");
        });

        function updateUserResults(data)
        {
            if(!data)
            {
                $("#user_search_results").empty();
                $("#user_search_results").append("<tr><td colspan='5'>No results</td></tr>");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#user_search_results").empty();
                for(var i in data)
                {
                    $("#user_search_results").append("<tr data-user-id='" + data[i]["id"] + "' data-label='" + data[i]["first_name"] + " " + data[i]["last_name"] + " [" + data[i]["id"] + "]'><td>" + data[i]["id"] + "</td><td>" + data[i]["first_name"] + "</td><td>" + data[i]["last_name"] + "</td><td>" + data[i]["city"] + "</td><td>" + data[i]["state"] + "</td></tr>");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you use the top cross to close the dialog ? Do you have the same problem in other browsers ?

Comment: When i hit the X on top (guessing that's what you ment by top cross) it does the same thing in firefox and chrome, leaves the shading from the modal option.  When I try to close it on IE it does nothing when i escape or the X on the top right, but when I select a User it closes the whole thing and the shading goes away, but it instally opens up dialog again with the info in it before I can do anything.

Comment: Is there any utility for you to keep the modal ? Can the user re-open it later ? If no, what if you replace `"close"` by `"destroy"` ?

Comment: I do need to have the user re open later.  Saying that i decided to give it a try anywase. Guess what?  Works perfect.  For some strange reason it still lets me reopen it too.  It either doesn't destroy the div or it rebuild, but I'm happy with it working.  If you submit it as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any utility for you to keep the modal ? Can the user re-open it later ? If no, what if you replace `"close"` by `"destroy"` ?